# MongoDB Count over 2 Collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I´m quite new to MongoDB and want to know the "best practice" way of counting and getting a maximum value out of 2 related documents.

Example is given below:
What is the best way to find the blogentry/blogentries with the most amount of likes?

Any advise is appreciated.

Here is the how the collections are set up:

```
------user------   
_id:ObjectId("user1")   
Name:"Alice"   
...

_id:ObjectId("user2")   
Name:"Bob"   
...   
------user------   


------blogentry------   
_id:ObjectId("entry1")   
...   
_id:ObjectId("entry2")   
...   
------blogentry------   


------like------   
_id:ObjectId("like1")   
user:ObjectId("user2")   
blogentry:ObjectId("entry3")   

...   
------like------
```

Comment: Sort descendingly and select the first one?

Comment: Consider using a more "read optimized" setup. E.g. add blogentry.numberOfLikes - now you can simply order your blog entries.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser,
do you really think that your suggested setup is the way to go? I am kind of used to regular SQL databases and the like-relation is a "n to m"-relation. The correct way of handeling this is to create a new like-table. Is this different in NoSQL databases?
What would your queries look like?
Cheers